# How to uncheck all checkboxes on click using jQuery except clicked one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I creating a form, where HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_60ao4_label" role="group"> <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-0"><label for="field_60ao4-0"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-0" value="Za mało śpię" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Za mało śpię</label></div>
<div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-1"><label for="field_60ao4-1"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-1" value="Jem o późnych porach" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Jem o późnych porach</label></div>
<div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-2"><label for="field_60ao4-2" class=""><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-2" value="Jem dużo soli" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Jem dużo soli</label></div>
<div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-3"><label for="field_60ao4-3" class=""><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-3" value="Jem słodycze" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Jem słodycze</label></div>
<div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-4"><label for="field_60ao4-4"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-4" value="Uwielbiam napoje gazowane" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Uwielbiam napoje gazowane</label></div>
<div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-5"><label for="field_60ao4-5" class=""><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-5" value="Za mało się ruszam" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Za mało się ruszam</label></div>
<div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-6"><label for="field_60ao4-6" class=""><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-6" value="Nie lubię ćwiczyć" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Nie lubię ćwiczyć</label></div>
<div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-7"><label for="field_60ao4-7" class=""><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-7" value="Nie mam czasu na treningi" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Nie mam czasu na treningi</label></div>
<div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-8"><label for="field_60ao4-8" class="checkedlabel"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-8" value="Żadne z powyższych" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Żadne z powyższych</label></div>
</div>
```

I need to add jQuery to last checkbox, so when someone click it, it will uncheck all except last checkbox.

**How can I do this using jQuery? Tried this but without success:**

```
$('#field_60ao4-8').click(function(){     
  $('#field_60ao4-8').attr('checked', false);
  $(this).attr('checked', true);          
   });
```

and:

```
    $(document).on('click','#field_60ao4-8', function(){     
      $('#field_60ao4-8').attr('checked', false);
      $(this).attr('checked', true);          
});
```

Comment: _"Tried a lot using code"_ Please post your attempts so that we don't waste our time duplicating your efforts

Comment: You must understand the selectors first. [Here the official guide of JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). In your case, a class selector should be for you: [direct link.](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: I can't change html because it's wordpress and external plugin. So i need to target ID.
checkedlabel is added by jQuery also, and when something is unchecked ckeckedlabel disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I figured out what you want, this code below is fine for you :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#field_60ao4-8').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $("div div input:not(:last)").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_60ao4_label" role="group">
  <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-0"><label for="field_60ao4-0"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-0" value="Za mało śpię" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Za mało śpię</label></div>
  <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-1"><label for="field_60ao4-1"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-1" value="Jem o późnych porach" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Jem o późnych porach</label></div>
  <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-2"><label for="field_60ao4-2" class=""><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-2" value="Jem dużo soli" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Jem dużo soli</label></div>
  <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-3"><label for="field_60ao4-3" class=""><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-3" value="Jem słodycze" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Jem słodycze</label></div>
  <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-4"><label for="field_60ao4-4"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-4" value="Uwielbiam napoje gazowane" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Uwielbiam napoje gazowane</label></div>
  <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-5"><label for="field_60ao4-5" class=""><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-5" value="Za mało się ruszam" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Za mało się ruszam</label></div>
  <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-6"><label for="field_60ao4-6" class=""><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-6" value="Nie lubię ćwiczyć" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Nie lubię ćwiczyć</label></div>
  <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-7"><label for="field_60ao4-7" class=""><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-7" value="Nie mam czasu na treningi" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Nie mam czasu na treningi</label></div>
  <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_111-8"><label for="field_60ao4-8" class="checkedlabel"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[111][]" id="field_60ao4-8" value="Żadne z powyższych" data-invmsg="Które stwierdzenia dotyczą ciebie is invalid"> Żadne z powyższych</label></div>
</div>
```

basically it just captures the `change` event of the last checkbox, and when is checked, it selects all child inputs of the child divs of the parent `div` without the last `input` element and set `checked` property of the selection to `false`.

Comment: This is what i need! Thanks!